# Using onclick event inside input tags in HTML to call a Javacscript function

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible in HTML to insert "onclick="function()" " like this:

```html
<input type="submit"  name="subm" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="js()" />
```

After this submit button is pressed I want to call the function js() which is included in the script. This function makes a control if one of my input fields with "tel" id contains characters or not.After submitting the form nothing outputs. Can someone help with this code so it can output the message inside the js()  function.

```html
<script>
  var a=getElementById("tel");
//tel is the id of a input field
function js(){
  
if((a.search(/[a-zA-Z]*/))!=-1){
 document.writeln("Tel nr mustn't contain charachters");
}
else document.writeln("The tel number is Ok");

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but a better option is to use event listeners. A full comparison of listener vs onclick is here: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

JS:

```
var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
sub.addEventListener("click", js);
```

### However! (Problem 1)

**Do not use `document.writeln()`**. That is because it will wipe the whole page clean if the function is triggered after loading the webpage. It is only meant for testing and not for productive usages. Please see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

### On top of that! (Problem 2)

You need a `type="button"` in your button to prevent the page from reloading!

### Furthermore (Problem 3)

You cannot do `a.search()`. `a` is an `element`, while you can only do `.search()` on a `string`. To get the value of the input, you need `a.value`.

### An then (Problem 4)

The regex won't work if you use `/[a-zA-Z]*/`. Try using `/[a-zA-Z]/`

### Besides (Problem 5)

There is no `getElementById()` function. There is only a `document.getElementById()` method. I don't know if you have added your own, but currently, this won't work.

---

Please see this example (I fixed all you errors):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("tel");
  var out = document.getElementById("output");
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", js);
  function js() {
    if (a.value.search(/[a-zA-Z]/) != -1)
      out.innerHTML = "Tel nr mustn't contain charachters";
    else
      out.innerHTML = "The tel number is Ok";

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tel">
<button type="button" id="btn">Click me :)</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: What if I want the message to output in the same page? Cause the type='button' outputs the message in another new page

Comment: @Doen To my knowledge, `type='button'` will not reload the page nor open up a new page. Anyway, please see my updated answer. I fixed many errors in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I think everything OK with your code but it still doesn't outputs anything

Comment: @Doen It needs `<p id="output"></p>` to exist within your webpage.

Comment: Yes! Finally I forgot the btn id. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `pattern` attribute that became available with html5? If you provide the pattern ( regex style ) then you get browser specific style notifications if a field's content violates the pattern - it also prevents the form from being submitted until the data is accepted according to the pattern.

To clarify @Daniel Cheung's answer - it does work and he should be credited for the answer ( very similar to what I'd have suggested )
 ~ I did modify his code slightly but not to the extent that it changes the behaviour.

What has not been addressed is the actual submission of the form. If you change from a standard `submit` input button to a regular `button` you will need to submit the form using javascript, but you'd need to ensure that there were no errors in the form's content first.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Form field onclick event listener</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var a = document.getElementById("tel");
                var out = document.getElementById("output");
                document.getElementById("bttn").addEventListener("click", js);

                function js() {
                  out.innerHTML = ( a.value.search(/[a-zA-Z]/) != -1 ) ? "Telephone numbers must not contain charachters, only numbers" : "The telephone number is Ok";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' id='fred'>
            <label>Username:<input type='text' name='username' id='username' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+' /></label>
            <label>Tel:<input type='text' name='tel' id='tel' pattern='[a-z0-9]{5,16}' /></label>
            <input type='button' name='subm' id='bttn' value='Submit' />
        </form>
        <output id='output'></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

A common method of validating a form and submitting if there are no issues is to assign an `onsubmit` event handler to the form itself. The event handler would do whatever processing of the data is required and return either true or false depending on whether or not there were any errors.

eg:

```
<form method='post' id='fred' onsubmit='return validateform( this )'></form>

function validateform( form ){
    var errors=false;
    /* do tests, displays messages */
    return errors ? false : true;
}
```

As I mentioned, this is really Daniel's code - just expanded ~ he should get credit for his answer - just adding my 10cents worth ;-)

Comment: I don't recommend putting digit limit on telephone number. You never know how long a number can be or how short it can be.

Comment: it was merely for example porpoises

Comment: Whale are you talking about?! That's a big deal for me. In fact, I've abandoned some application forms because they had max limits and I couldn't fill them in.